# reference for valid rates, ratios, normalization, etc

Tags: normalization, ratio

I'm compiling a list of valid ratios that can be used in analysis. For example, # of sub population / # of population, amount by sub population / number in sub population, etc...

I'm having trouble finding an authoritative source of information that breaks down the possibilities and best practices. Does something like this exist for rates/ratios/normalization just based off of a few rules of thumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the general categorical data analysis perspective - keyword: 'table standardization' -  I found Fleiss, Levin, and Paik's [Statistical Methods for Rates and Proportions](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471526290.html) quite useful.  It seems to have expanded quite a lot since the edition I have on my shelf.  In any case, Chapter 19 'The Standardization of Rates' is the part you may want to look at.

You may also want to search for 'raking', 'IPF', and 'post-stratification', often in the survey sampling literature.  Most texts should cover these topics.  They are mostly generalizations of your question, so should provide some useful principles.